# A variation of Borel Cantelli Lemma

Tags: probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf, borel-cantelli-lemmas

If $P(A_n) \rightarrow 0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{P(A_n^c\cap A_{n+1}})<\infty$ then $P(A_n \text{ i.o.})=0$.

How to prove this? Thanks.

Comment: Probably $P(\limsup A_n)$. (infinitely often). Further continuity from above/below of the measure.

Comment: How do you prove this if the complement is switched, i.e. if we know $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{P(A_n\cap A_{n+1}^c})<\infty $$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hint:  $\lim \sup A_n \subseteq A_N \cup \bigcup_{n=N}^\infty (A^c_n \cap A_{n+1})$.  Estimate the probability of this.

Comment: Do you think the RHS will go to 0 if we take probability in both side?

Answer (score -1):

$$P[A_n^c\ i.o.] = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} P[\bigcup_{n=N}^{\infty} A_n^c] \geq \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} P(A_n^c) = 1\Longrightarrow P[A_{n+1}^c\ i.o.] = 1$$
But from $1st$ Borel-Cantelli Lemma, we know $P[A_n\cap A_{n+1}^c\ i.o.] = 0$, as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(A_n\cap A_{n+1}^c) < \infty$.
$$P[A_n\cap A_{n+1}^c\ i.o.] = 0\\\Rightarrow \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} P[\bigcup_{n=N}^{\infty} A_n\cap A_{n+1}^c] = 0\\
\Rightarrow \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} P[(\cup_{n=N}^{\infty} A_n)\cap (\cup_{n=N}^{\infty} A_{n+1}^c)] = 0\\
\Rightarrow \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} P[(\cup_{n=N}^{\infty} A_n)] + \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} P[(\cup_{n=N}^{\infty} A_{n+1}^c)] - \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} P[(\cup_{n=N}^{\infty} A_n)\cup (\cup_{n=N}^{\infty} A_{n+1}^c)] = 0\\
\Rightarrow P[A_n\ i.o.] + 1 - 1 = 0$$
Hence, we have showed the required result.

Comment: Here, I have addressed the question with @nelson's commented condition where the complements are switched. But it can clearly be seen it doesn't matter whether the condition is as in the Qsn or with the complements switched. As if we go by the O.P.'s condition we will end up with $P[A_{n+1}\ i.o.] = 0$, which is necessarily the same thing.

Comment: You seem to claim $$ \bigcup _{m=N}^\infty A_m \cap A_{m+1}^c = \bigcup _{m=N}^\infty A_m \cap \bigcup _{n=N}^\infty A_{n+1}^c $$
but this is not true. The LHS is only a diagonal part of the RHS. How do we conclude said probability is zero?