# Show that finitely many $A_n$ will occur

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I tried this problem quite a bit but went nowhere. I wish to solve this using set-theoretic algebra.

**Problem statement**

Let $A_n$, $n \geq 1$ be a sequence of events such that $ \mathbb P(A_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, and

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb P (A_{n+1}\setminus A_{n}) <\infty$$

Show that almost surely, only finitely many of the $A_n$s will occur.

While irrelevant, it might be worth mentioning this problem is from [MIT OCW](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-436j-fundamentals-of-probability-fall-2008/assignments/MIT6_436JF08_hw02.pdf) (Exercise 3).

**My attempt**

I did not get very far. While it is obvious that we have to use Borel-Cantelli lemma on the hypothesis, it did not lead me anywhere. Specifically, since we know that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb P (A_{n+1}\setminus A_{n}) <\infty$$

we can conclude that

$$\mathbb P \left ( \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k = n}^{\infty} A_{n+1}\setminus A_{n} \right ) = 0$$

Using the above and the hypothesis that $ \mathbb P(A_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, we need to somehow show that

$$\mathbb P \left ( \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k = n}^{\infty} A_{k} \right ) = 0$$

I tried a lot of set algebra but it did not lead me anywhere.

I did see a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583734/probability-of-limsup-of-a-sequence-of-sets-borel-cantelli-lemma) which is similar to this one but the hypothesis is slightly different. It mentions

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb P (A_{n}\setminus A_{n+1}) <\infty$$

instead of

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb P (A_{n+1}\setminus A_{n}) <\infty$$

as given in this problem. More importantly, I wish to solve this problem using set-theoretic algebra rather than arguments on lim sup etc.

I would be grateful if you can provide some insight or a  hint in order for me to prove this using set-theoretic methods (ie using infinite unions, intersections, De-Morgan's laws etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
P(\cup_{k=n}^\infty A_k)
&=[P(A_n)+ P(A_{n+1}A_n^c)+P(A_{n+2}A_{n+1}^cA_n^c)+\dotsb]\\
&\leq P(A_n)+\sum_{k=n}^\infty P(A_{k+1}\setminus A_{k})\to 0
\end{align}
$$
as $n\to \infty$. The result follows from measure continuity.

Comment: So I gather that $A_2 \cup A_1 = A_1 \cup(A_2 \cap A_1^c)$, $A_3 \cup A_2 \cup A_1 = A_1 \cup(A_2 \cap A_1^c) \cup(A_3 \cap A_2^c \cap A_1^c)$ etc. This when extended to infinity gives the expression that you mentioned. 

Also, defining $B_n = \cup_{k=n}^\infty A_k$, we want to show that 

$$\mathbb P \left ( \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty}B_n \right ) = 0$$

or as $B_{n+1} \subset B_n$, we need to show that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}P(B_n) = 0 $$

Comment: So you are saying that 

$$
\begin{align}
P(B_n)
&=[P(A_n)+ P(A_{n+1} \cap A_n^c)+P(A_{n+2} \cap A_{n+1}^c \cap A_n^c)+\dotsb]\\
&\leq P(A_n)+\sum_{k=n}^\infty P(A_{k+1}\setminus A_{k})\to 0
\end{align}
$$
as $n\to \infty$ which basically solves the problem. I suppose the above expression simply did the trick. I wonder how you thought of this expression. :)

Thanks a lot for the help!