# If $\mu(E_{n})\to 0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_{n+1}\setminus E_{n}) < \infty$, show that $\mu(\limsup E_{n}) = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The question is: Given a collection of measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ $\{E_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and the Lebesgue measure $\mu$. If $\mu(E_{n})\to 0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_{n+1}\setminus E_{n}) < \infty$, show that $\mu(\limsup E_{n}) = 0$.

My take on this problem is try to follow the proof of the Borel–Cantelli lemma. If we let $B_{N} = \bigcup_{n=N}^{\infty} E_{n}$, then $\bigcap_{N} B_{N} = \limsup E_{n}$. By continuity from above, we have $\mu(B_{N})\to \mu(\limsup E_{n}) = 0$.

But in order to use continuity from above, we have to prove $\mu(B_{N}) < \infty$ for some $N$. Thus I was wondering whether I could prove $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} E_{n} < \infty$ for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ by the 2 conditions, $\mu(E_{n})\to 0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_{n+1}\setminus E_{n}) < \infty$, I was given.

Is this approach the way to solve the problem or am I on the wrong track?
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Could you just use $B_N:=\cup_{n=N}^\infty (E_{n+1}\setminus E_n)$ instead?

Comment: Note that $B_N = E_N\cup\bigcup_{n=N}^\infty (E_{n+1}\setminus E_n)$.

Comment: @amsmath Thanks! I've written $\limsup E_{n} = \bigcap_{N} B_{N} = \bigcap_{N}[E_{N}\cup (\bigcup_{n=N}^{\infty} E_{n+1}\setminus E_{n})]$. But how do I expand the right hand side?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/42037/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/583734/321264

Comment: @cici30725 I don't understand your question. The representation of $B_N$ shows that $\mu(B_N) < \infty$. And that was what you were looking for, right?

Comment: @amsmath I was looking at the wrong direction but now I got it now. Thank you so much!