# Borel-Cantelli lemma problem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Practice problem for exam:

> Let ${A_n}$ satisfy $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n \cap A^c_{n+1}) < \infty$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} P(A_n) = 0$.  Show that $P(\lim \sup A_n) = 0$.

I can see that it is sufficient to show that $P\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right) < \infty$ and then apply the Borel-Cantelli lemma, but I am having trouble showing this from the information given.  I see an almost identical problem here: [A variation of Borel Cantelli Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42037/a-variation-of-borel-cantelli-lemma), however the hint there is not enough for me to make headway, and this problem is also different in which term gets the complement inside the first sum.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have

$$\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty A_n = \bigcup_{n=k}^\infty \left(A_n\setminus A_{n+1}\right) \cup \bigcap_{n=k}^\infty A_n\tag{1}$$

for all $k$. Apply the Borel-Cantelli lemma to $B_n = A_n\setminus A_{n+1}$ and note that because of $(1)$ you have $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} A_n = \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} B_n \cup \liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} A_n$. You know $P\left(\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} A_n\right) = 0$ from $P(A_n) \to 0$.

Comment: How did the equality you write above follows from (1), I could not see it, thanks in advance

Comment: In $(1)$, we can replace $\bigcap A_n$ with $\liminf A_n$, since that contains the intersection, and is contained in the union on the left hand side. That is then independent of $k$, so we can pull it out of the $\limsup$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Why are we guaranteed that $P(lim inf An)=0$ when $P(A_n)\rightarrow 0$?