# Events $\{A_n\}$ satisfy $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(A_n)=0$ and $\sum\limits_n P(A_nA_{n+1}^c)<\infty$, show that $P(A_n ~\text{i.o.})=0$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

> Suppose $\{A_n\}$ is a sequence of events such that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(A_n)=0$ and $\sum\limits_n P(A_nA_{n+1}^c)<\infty$, show that $P(A_n ~\text{i.o.})=0$.

I do not know how to prove this problem. Can anybody give some suggestions?

---

I find an answer which is easy to understand
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/640842/383241

Comment: What can you conclude about $P[A_n A_{n+1}^c \: f.o.]$? What events imply or are implied by $\{A_n A_{n+1}^c \: f.o.\} \cap \{A_n \: i.o\}$?