# Borel Cantelli Lemma

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to show the following version of borel-Cantelli Lemma:

Suppose $A_n\in \mathcal{F}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(A_n\cap A_{n+1}^{c})<\infty$ and $P(A_n)\rightarrow 0$ then $P(A_n i.o)=0$

The way I tried to show it was using the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(A_n\cap A_{n+1}^{C})<\infty$
implies $P(A_n\cap A_{n+1}^c \hspace{2mm}i.o)=0$ which implies $P(A_n^c\cup A_{n+1} \hspace{2mm} a.a)=1$

Then looking at the behavior of $\omega \in \{A_n^c\cup A_{n+1} \hspace{2mm} a.a\}$ I figures that this implies there exists an n such that $\omega \in \cap_{k\ge n} (A_k^c\cup A_{k+1})$ but this implies that if $\omega \in A_{n}^c\cap A_{n+1}$ then $\omega \in \cup_{k\ge n+1}A_k$. If $\omega \in A_{n}^c$ only then it is either in $A_{n+1}^c$ or $A_{n+2}$ if it is in both then $\omega \in \cup_{k\ge n+2}A_k$. Following the same logic I conclude that $\{A_n^c\cup A_{n+1} \hspace{2mm} a.a\}\subset\{(\cup_{n=1}\cap_{k\ge n}A_k) \cup (\cup_{n=1}\cap_{k\ge n}A_n^c)\}$

Then this implies

$$1=P(A_n^c\cup A_{n+1} \hspace{2mm} a.a\}\le P(\cup_{n=1}\cap_{k\ge n}A_k)+P(\cup_{n=1}\cap_{k\ge n}A_n^c)$$

Then
$$P(\cup_{n=1}\cap_{k\ge n}A_k)=P(A_n \hspace{3mm} a.a)=0$$

since $P(A_n)\rightarrow 0$. Which gives my desired result. Is my logic correct?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/640832/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/583734/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/42037/321264.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks for the clue. I have updated my response using the hint $P(A_n)\rightarrow 0$ then $P(A_n\hspace{4mm}a.a)=0$. Does the rest of my solution have any validity or have I made a mistake somewhere?