# Question on a variation of Borel Cantelli Lemma

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf, borel-cantelli-lemmas

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42037/a-variation-of-borel-cantelli-lemma), what is the purpose of the summation?

If the limit of the sequence is zero, the corresponding series is convergent. Does the desired conclusion not then follow from BC1?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, pls be more precise

Comment: @LiuGang In the question, there is a summation given. Is it necessary? If so, how?

Comment: The summation is used to show $\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}P(A_n^c\cap A_{n+1}) = 0$. Without it we can't reach the conclusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true that if $a_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges.

The most widely known counterexample is that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 n=\infty$.

Comment: I can't believe I confused that with the converse. Thanks :))